# crystal report version

Tags: asp.net

how do i find the version of crystal report in visual studio 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of the DLLs in the installation directory ({install-dir}\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Crystal Reports) indicate they belong to version 10.2.

As far as I know the within Visual Studio 2005 distributed version of Crystal Reports is officially called "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005".

Answer (score 0):

Go to Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio, then Crystal Reports should be in the Installed products list.